# How to join 2 tables in cypher, NEO4J

Tags: neo4j, match, cypher, join

The query is:

"List of movies in Games category having rental rate of more than $4 "

There are two tables, "Film" and "Film_category" both have a common attribute, "film_id"

How to solve this query, I read the documentation of how to join tables, didn't understand a word, Please help me out!

Comment: Neo4j doesn't have tables silly.

Comment: by tables I mean the relations, the graphs.

Answer (score 2):

[Edited]

Assuming (from the earlier version of your question) that the following properties all belong to nodes with the `Film` label:

- film_id
- title
- rental_rate
- replacement_cost
- rental_value

, that the following properties all belong to `Film_category`:

- category_name

, and that the model looks like:

```
(:Film)-[:HAS_CATEGORY]->(:Film_category)
```

, then this query will answer your question:

```
MATCH (f:Film)-[:HAS_CATEGORY]->(c:Film_category)
WHERE f.rental_value > 4.0 AND c.category_name = 'Game'
RETURN f;
```

Comment: I'm really sory, I pasted the wrong query, the right one is
"List of movies in Games category having rental rate of more than $4"